# Update rows in SQL every 20 iterations

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with ~1 million rows in Google BigQuery from [the NYC Yellow TaxiCab public dataset](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/downloads/pdf/data_dictionary_trip_records_yellow.pdf). As you can see from that link, the schema does not have a primary key. Each row represents a trip/transaction, but there is no `customer_id` field.

I want to add a column `customer_id` and distribute random numbers to it such that:

```
For rows 1-20, `customer_id` should be assigned `1`
For rows 21-40, `customer_id` should be assigned `2`
and so on..
```

In other words, I want exactly (and any) 20 rows in the table to have a specific value of `customer_id`.

Comment: How would you sort these rows? Meaning, what's the meaning of "row number 1"? Note that in SQL world rows have no order, until you give them one.

Comment: Is there a way to add a field to a table such that it increments after every 20 rows.

Comment: but why? understanding the use case might get us to an alternative answer that solves the problem

Comment: I want to see aggregates for ~1 million customers with 20 rows each. So i want a customer to have 20 transactions in the table

Comment: assign totally random rows to each customer? does it have to be 20, or can each id get around 17~23 rows?

Comment: Actually I don't have a primary key in my table. I am trying to map a transaction to a customer. I have ~1 million transactions without the customer id. I want ~20 transctions to be mapped to a single customer

Comment: the question still is: assign any ~20 random rows to each fictional customer? o

Comment: Yes. any 20 rows to each customer. thus, ~1million/20 should have approx 5000 customer_ids

Comment: 50000 customer_ids*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign each row a random id, getting groups of ~20 rows for each `new_id`:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(COUNT(*) OVER()/20*RAND()) AS INT64) new_id, *
FROM (
  SELECT login
  FROM `ghtorrent-bq.ght_2017_04_01.users`
  LIMIT 1000000
)
```

Proof that 50,000 "customers_ids" are generated when going over a million rows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and produces exactly 20 entries per customer_id

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER() - 1, 20) AS customer_id, *
FROM `yourTable`
-- ORDER BY customer_id
```

You can test play with this using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourTable` AS (
    SELECT login
    FROM `ghtorrent-bq.ght_2017_04_01.users`
    LIMIT 1000000
)
SELECT DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER() - 1, 20) AS customer_id, *
FROM `yourTable`
-- ORDER BY customer_id
```

Moreover - below query shows the distribution of counts per customer_id

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourTable` AS (
    SELECT login
    FROM `ghtorrent-bq.ght_2017_04_01.users`
    LIMIT 1000000
)
SELECT cnt, COUNT(1) AS distribution FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM (
    SELECT *, DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER() - 1, 20) AS customer_id
    FROM `yourTable`
    ORDER BY customer_id
  )
  GROUP BY customer_id
)
GROUP BY cnt
ORDER BY cnt
```

with output as below

```sql
Row cnt distribution     
--- --- ------------
1    20        50000
```

Comment: I thought of this one, but then I wanted to avoid `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` for scalability reasons (no `PARTITION` will make this fail if too much data in the columns)

Comment: agree. :o) using ROW_NUMBER() not something to recommend in any case, but in this case PO mentioned `I have a table with ~1 million rows` so I thought it makes sense for him to try as it gives exact distribution he wanted (20 entries per id)

Comment: Thanks guys. Also, is there any way to do this for ~10 million records. BigQuery breaks saying resources exceeded. there has to be a way to do this in batches or something? 10 million records for 500000 customers (assuming 20 rows per customer).

Comment: @AkshayApte - I've just tried both my and Felipe's solutions and both worked for 10M of course with the difference of exact distributions of 20 rows per 500000 customers vs. bell-shaped distribution in Felipe's answer. So what exactly is not working for you? please clarify! I would recommend asking new question posting your exact final query with error you are getting so we can help effectively rather than just commenting.